# Windows 7 and Ubuntu 18?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, 18.04

I'm using windows 7 and I want a dual boot with ubuntu 18.04. The installation is giving me a fail all time. Error to install GRUB. It can be because Windows 7 is EFI and Ubuntu 18.04 UEFI or something like that? Can I do the dual boot?

Comment: Hi Marc, it does matter what mode each OS is installed in (UEFI or BIOS). First please check what mode your Windows is installed in. Start up Windows, type `Win + R` and enter `msinfo32`. There will be an entry called "BIOS Mode" which will have either the value of "BIOS" or "UEFI". (See [this tutorial](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot.html). Also, you might want to check whether you have a 32 or 64 bit installation of Windows 7.

Comment: While in Windows, press the Start button, right-click on Computer, select Properties, and you can see whether it's 32 or 64.

Comment: Please include that information in your question, as well as: 1) which version of Ubuntu you're attempting to install--is it 18.04 or 18.10? 2) your installation method (CD/DVD/USB stick) 3) if you're installing from a live USB, include the file name of the ISO you downloaded

Comment: Hey @Emily, thanks for your response! I don't find any BIOS or UEFI in msinfo32 :S, is a Windows 7 64 bits version, and the ubuntu is 18.04.

Comment: No problem! Oops, I forgot to look for directions specific to Win 7. Find `setupact.log` in `C:\Windows\Panther` (a directory containing setup logs). Open it in Notepad, and search for `Callback_BootEnvironmentDetect: Detected boot environment`. Next to that you should see either BIOS or EFI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after trying 10 times... Finally I could install it with [Wubi](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/releases) it's a software for install ubuntu from a Windows software.

Comment: Wubi has not been supported since 12.04. I thought they finally removed it from the download ISO?

Comment: I have not installed ubuntu with ISO, I executed Wubi from a Windows exe and it worked